# Tomcat service on windows server 2019 starts automatically after being killed?

Tags: services, tomcat

I have to regularly kill my tomcat service on a windows server 2019 in order to transfer new data into an MSSQL database. I have administrator privilages and have tried all methods I know to stop the service indefinately.

1. start cmd as Administrator > taskkill /F /PID pid_number
2. start cmd as Administrator >taskkill /IM “process name” /F
3. start services.msc as Administrator > stop service
4. process explorer > kill process
   However, after stopping the service it starts again about 1-2 minutes later.

What could be monitoring the tomcat service and starts it again?

Answer (score 0):

Windows will automatically restart it because it is a *service*, and Windows is trying to keep it up and running.  I suggest that you run `services.msc` and stop the service there.  Then Windows will shut it down and keep it down until you start the service again.

I generally use `Get-Service`, `Stop-Service`, and `Start-Service` in Powershell because it is easier for me than finding the service I'm looking for in a long list.

HTH